# replaceWith inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I want that every 1000 millieconds my element obj get replaced by the new element created by my function myPlugin.

The problem is that the element is not being replaced.

I guess that the issue is coming from disclosure or something like that. Too lazy to think anymore at 6 am, I just want an answer :)

**Plunker** : https://plnkr.co/edit/J9k6kFc0yWySXKFwBdB1?p=preview

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.myCrypto').each(function(i, obj) {
      window.setInterval(function() {
        var a = myPlugin(obj.getAttribute("cf_widget_size"), obj.getAttribute("cf_widget_from"), obj.getAttribute("cf_widget_to"), obj.getAttribute("cf_clearstyle"));
        obj.replaceWith(a);
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

body

```
<div>
  <div class="myCrypto" cf_widget_size="large" cf_widget_from="BTC" cf_widget_to="usd" cf_clearstyle=true></div>
</div>
```

myPlugin

```
function myPlugin( cf_widget_size,  cf_widget_from,  cf_widget_to,  cf_clearstyle) {
    var t = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1],
        n = t.parentElement,
        r = document.createElement("iframe"),
        i = "https://www.worldcoinindex.com/widget/renderWidget?size=" + cf_widget_size + "&from=" + cf_widget_from + "&to=" + cf_widget_to + "&clearstyle=" + cf_clearstyle;
        if (cf_widget_size == "small") {
            r.width = "300px";
            r.height = "135px"
        } else if (cf_widget_size == "medium") {
            r.width = "300px";
            r.height = "240px"
        } else if (cf_widget_size == "large") {
            r.width = "300px";
            r.height = "340px"
        }
    r.id = "cf_widget_iframe"
    r.setAttribute("data-size", cf_widget_size);
    r.style.cssText = "border:none;"; -1 == navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") ? r.src = i : r.location = i;
    console.log("hahah");
    return (r);
  };
```

Comment: What's the "issue"? Do you mean the jQuery `replaceWith` function? It is not mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post."The problem is that the element is not being replaced."

Comment: if (typeof cf_widget_mode != "undefined") , what is cf_widget_mode in your if clause

Comment: can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain something irrelevant in this case, I'm going to delete it.

Comment: @orangespark it's my first time using it, I added the plunkr. Let me know if it's not working.

Comment: I think it's working...

Comment: @fab No it doesn't. i'm using setInterval to refresh the widget. But as you can see nothing is being refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace the `obj` with the new `a` objcect

```
obj.replaceWith(a);
obj = a;
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/xqmepXXU9J86sPe0H76a?p=preview

Comment: Alright, it's working correctly.However, I think you noticed that after its reload, the widget is not working anymore. I guess it's because as the object get replaced its attribute doesn't exist anymore. So I tried to set some attribute but this new object "a" cannot call the .attr function. What should I do ? As soon as you answered me your answer will be accepted. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here -

1. `setInterval` is inside `$.each`. This way selector is executed only once and then expects the element in `setInterval` function every 1000 ms which will be replaced in the first iteration.
2. `myPlugin` should assign the class `.myCrypto` to the element it returns so that it can be selected with the same class selector again.
3. `cf_widget_size=large` and other properties that are mentioned in the html should be re-assigned to the element (iframe) being returned.

Check this fiddle for what I'm trying to say. https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilgirraj/jv0h1gLm/

Comment: Instead of replacing the element every time. You should probably look into reloading the frame that you have once created, like doing `document.getElementById('#myFrame').src = document.getElementById('#myFrame').src;`

Comment: Can you give me a working example in this situation ?